# How to understand functor from or to empty category?

Tags: category-theory

**What is the definition of an empty category?** I know it is a category with no objects and no morphisms, so does it mean it is a small category? Can we also denote it as $\emptyset$

A functor between locally small categories ($C$ and $D$) can be defined as (**I do not know whether my definition is true or not since I found seldom people define it using symbols (Why?), but I just prefer symbols**) :

1.$\forall x$ ($x$ is an object of $C \longrightarrow F(x)$ is an object of $D)$

2.$\forall x,y$(x,y are objects of $C)$, $\forall f \in C(x,y)$, $F(f) \in D(F(x),F(y))$

I skipped the other properties since they can be expressed similarly.

So, if $C$ is the empty category, how can we define a functor form $C$ to $D$, it seems to me $F$ can be anything since all the above statements are vacuously true. **(Not like the case for functions since we additionally require a function to be the subset of $A \times B$)**

Moreover, if $D$ is the empty category, how can we define a functor form $C$ to $D$?

It seems to me that if we only consider locally small categories, then the functor does have some 'function' properties on the 'morphism sets', so from the property 2, can I show (No functor between $C \longrightarrow  $ empty category, empty functor from empty category $\longrightarrow  $ empty category, empty functor from empty category $\longrightarrow  $ $D$)?

But if the 'morphism sets' are not sets? ie. We do not restrict functors defined between locally small categories? Without the restriction of function, it seems to me $F$ can be anything since all the above statements are vacuously true.

Comment: Just like with sets: the only functor from the empty category to a category $D$ is the empty functor. If $C$ is a category, then there are no functors from $C$ to the empty category if $C$ is nonempty, and only the empty functor if $C$ is empty.

Comment: You are using an incomplete definition of a functor. This may be the reason why you don't see the analogy to functions from and to the empty set so easily. Please look up the definition.

Comment: I searched but still do not know why I used an incomplete definition of a functor.

Comment: Yes, I know. A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ needs to be a subset of $A \times B$, so whenever $A$ or $B$ is empty, the only possible function is the empty function. But for a functor, does it also need to be some 'subset' of $C \times D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the definition of an empty category?

The empty category is the category whose object class is the empty set. It is therefore small by definition. The empty category is often denoted simply by $0$, though typically not by $\emptyset$, which is usually reserved for the empty set.

> I do not know whether my definition is true or not since I found seldom people define it using symbols (Why?), but I just prefer symbols

Writing an entire definition symbolically often makes it harder to read, and mathematicians generally assume the reader is able to translate a definition in natural language to set theory, should they want to.

> 1.∀ ( is an object of ⟶() is an object of )
> 2.∀, (x,y are objects of ) , ∀∈(,), ()∈((),())

This doesn't make sense as is. $\forall$ is used to quantify over propositions (i.e. statements that are true or false), not to define structure. A functor from $C$ to $D$ can be defined formally as a pair:

1. A function $|F| : |C| \to |D|$.
2. A function $F : \prod_{x, y \in |C|} C(x, y) \to D(|F|x, |F|y)$
   satisfying the functoriality conditions.

> So, if  is the empty category, how can we define a functor form  to

We need:

1. A function $|F| : \emptyset \to |D|$. This is uniquely determined, because there is only one function from the empty set to any other set.
2. A function $F : \prod_{x, y \in \emptyset} 0(x, y) \to D(|F|x, |F|y)$. This is trivial, since the empty category $0$ has no objects.

Thus there is a unique functor from the empty category to any category $D$.

> Moreover, if  is the empty category, how can we define a functor form  to ?

We need:

1. A function $|F| : |C| \to \emptyset$. Such a function only exists if $|C|$ is also the empty set, hence only if $C$ is the empty category.
2. A function $F : \prod_{x, y \in |C|} C(x, y) \to 0(|F|x, |F|y)$. Since we must assume $C$ is also the empty category, this function is also uniquely determined.

Thus the only category with a functor to the empty category is the empty category, and the only such functor is the identity functor.

> But if the 'morphism sets' are not sets?

If you are working with large categories that are not locally small, the same statements apply. Just replace "set" with "class" in the above. Nothing fundamentally changes about the behaviour of functors between locally small categories versus large categories.

Comment: So, if  is the empty category, how can we define a functor form  to ? If  is a small category, then your statements hold. But if  is just a locally small category, $Ob(D)$ is not a set, so the functor works on $Ob(C)$ to $Ob(D) does not have the function property. How can I know the only choice for it is still the empty function?

Comment: @Andrew_Ren: functions [can be defined between classes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/class+function+%28set+theory%29), not just sets. Nothing I have stated relies on the object classes being sets.